# SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services: "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, windows-server

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services on Windows Server 2008, but all the web interface says after adding the feature and confirming all the default settings in Reporting Services Configuration Manager is

> Error: Unable to connect to the remote server

In the logfile there is this message:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80

This worked just few months ago on the same system.

Comment: You installed Reporting Services on a machine but did you also install the Database Engine? RS needs to have access to database to create two catalogs. Also, I'm a little confused. If it was working a few months ago, why are you re-installing?

Comment: The machine works as a DB server also, so there is a functional instance of MSSQL and Reporting Services succesfully created ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB for its use. Sorry for being unclear -- RS stopped working at some point (with the mentioned error message) without an obvious reason and my problem is that even re-install doesn't work.

Comment: Could this be a mismatch in your configuration with one end using the RTSPS protocol and the other end is configured to use the RTSP protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem when installing SSRS for a SCOM installation.  It was configured with SSL but when I removed this I started getting the same error as above. Solution was to change the SecureConnectionLevel in rsreportserver.config to 0.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/686214/removing-ssl-cert-in-config-manager-doesnt-properly-modify-rsreportserver-config